# How to kill the big green monster in Magicka?

Tags: magicka

In Magicka on the second chapter. In the beginning of the chapter there is a big green monster. what spells do I use to kill it?

Comment: All of them[!](http://#)

Comment: The answers below are perfectly fine, but the wonderful thing about Magicka is that there are *many, many, many* ways to kill most creatures, including yourself!

Comment: @CRoss Including? *Especially* yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lightning, Arcane, Cold - Freezey shocker beam o death!

Check this out, http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1733437

Comment: My favorite combo in the game.  Lots O' damage, plus slow movement.  Also reasonably effective as AoE when surrounded.

Comment: and getting it wet first will increase the damage substantially, and freeze it solid!

Answer (score 4):

Lightning + Arcane -> Target -> Kill :D

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean the troll? You don't even have to kill the first one...You can walk right up to it, and examine the moose he's eating. But if you do hit him, he'll attack, and you'll be in trouble.

Here is a spell for you, memorize it and you will conquer...BEHOLD THE MIGHT OF:
**SQFQFAA**

Arcane+Steam+Steam+Lightning+Lightning=the most destructive beam attack in the game. Practice it, and you will turn huge slow moving monsters into paste. You can also use it as an AoE, and it excels there as well. Put it on your weapon! It's good there too! It slices, it dices, it chops!

Comment: If you find SQFQFAA takes too much keystrokes to type though, you can try SQFAAA. It does a little less damage, but not considerably. (The AoE does about 5% less damage)

Comment: @arda: I can hammer that thing out in an instant now, and I'm not an especially good typist. Just takes some practice.

Comment: will try that for the next stage

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you are quick enough, you can kill pretty much anything in the game 1 v 1 if you make it wet then ice it. From that point on, just hit it with any spell that includes ice and it will maintain the frozen status no matter what other damage you hit it with, unless you hit it with water/steam/fire.